# Why I cannot use the keyword of init for defining protocols and enums in Swift?

Tags: swift

I want use the key word of init inside my protocol or enum like this:

```
protocol Initializable {
    static func init(value: String)
}
```

---

```
enum MyEnum {
    case a, b, c
    static func init(value: String) { }
}
```

but Xcode says: Keyword `init` cannot be used as an identifier here! so why not? and if
i use help of error it will correct it to `'init'`, not sure of `'init'` and `init` are the same thing here or what are difference here, need help to understand it.

Comment: You can't have a function named `init`. It needs to just be an initializer, called `init` (No "static func" before it)

Comment: But there is still error and issue exists even if i remove static.

Comment: Well did you also remove `func`?

Comment: Oh no, if i remove the keyword of `func` the issue goes away.

Comment: To take it from the start, you should not use `init` as a name in your protocol for a function, static or not, but only use this keyword if it is an actual initialiser that you want as part of the protocol and then it should be properly declared as one, `init(value: String)`. Otherwise you choose some other word, `static func create(value: String)`or something.

Answer (score 0):

At first, I thought you forgot to use backticks:

```swift
static func `init`(value: String)
```

```swift
MyEnum.`init`(value: "")
```

But reading the comments, it seems that you didn't know that Swift has initializers, which are somewhat different than functions. Use that instead.

```swift
protocol Initializable {
  init(value: String)
}
```

(I find using `init` useful only rarely, e.g. for parameter names.)

```swift
public extension Decodable {
  /// Initialize using 2 keyed, decoded arguments.
  /// - Parameters:
  ///   - init: An initializer (or  factory function) whose arguments are the decoded values.
  ///   - keys: `CodingKey` instances, matching the arguments.
  init<Parameter0: Decodable, Parameter1: Decodable, Key: CodingKey>(
    _ init: (Parameter0, Parameter1) -> Self,
    _ keys: (Key, Key),
    decoder: Decoder
  ) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: Key.self)
    self = try `init`(
      container.decode(forKey: keys.0),
      container.decode(forKey: keys.1)
    )
  }
}
```